# Fetch a variable value from the target server in RPM

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I want to read a variable value from the target server in the `%install` script. When I try to package the script, it searches the file where I am packaging and fails to find it. Is there any option to read the files on target server without such failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions that need to be performed on the target machine instead of the build machine should be done in the `%pre` or `%post` scriplets, depending on whether they should be performed before or after installation.

For more information on these scriptlets, see [this section of *Maximum RPM*](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html#S2-RPM-INSIDE-ERASE-TIME-SCRIPTS).